# Activity does not start

Tags: android, android-activity

I use this code to start a new Game from my `MainMenu`, everything works fine but when a game is finished the users get a popup Window (just another Activity named `GameFinished` with `Theme.Dialog`). The users can chose if they want to play the game again or go back to the `MainMenu`. This also works fine, but when I start another game the Activity from my `MainMenu` nothing happens, the debugger shows that the line is executed.

Visual Guide:

A --> B --> C --finish--> B --finish--> A

After that I cannot this:

A --> B

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

    if (id == 0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(GameMenu.this, GuessFlag.class));
                    } else if (id == 1) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(GameMenu.this,
                                MovieQuestions.class));
                    } else if (id == 2) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(GameMenu.this, SimpleMath.class));
                    } else if (id == 3) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(GameMenu.this, TickTacToe.class));
                    }
                }
```

The only thing I added in a few weeks was this line so I [Tapifier](http://www.tapifier.com) would work:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

This is my (very big) logcat:

```
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311): Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.MovieQuestions has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@42342078 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.MovieQuestions has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@42342078 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.<init>(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:332)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.installDecor(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:176)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.MovieQuestions.onCreate(MovieQuestions.java:45)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-16 17:17:28.845: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311): Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.SimpleMath has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@423555f8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.SimpleMath has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@423555f8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.<init>(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:332)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.installDecor(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:176)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.SimpleMath.onCreate(SimpleMath.java:46)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-16 17:17:29.900: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311): Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.MovieQuestions has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@4294f240 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.MovieQuestions has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@4294f240 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.<init>(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:332)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.installDecor(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:176)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.MovieQuestions.onCreate(MovieQuestions.java:45)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-16 17:17:30.520: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311): Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@4296a908 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@4296a908 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.<init>(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:332)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.installDecor(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:176)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag.onCreate(GuessFlag.java:46)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-16 17:17:30.825: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311): Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.SimpleMath has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@429858b0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.SimpleMath has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@429858b0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.<init>(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:332)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.installDecor(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:176)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.SimpleMath.onCreate(SimpleMath.java:46)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-16 17:17:31.225: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311): Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@429a0de0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$1@429a0de0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.<init>(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:332)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent.installDecor(MultiPhoneWindowEvent.java:176)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag.onCreate(GuessFlag.java:46)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-16 17:17:31.500: E/ActivityThread(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SimpleMath:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_simpemath);


        }

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (AppData.questionsLoaded) {
        AppData.questionsLoaded  = false;
        runGame();
    }

    if (AppData.restartGame) {
        AppData.restartGame = false;
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(SimpleMath.this, TickTacToe.class));
    }

    if(AppData.finishMe){
        finish();
    }

}
```

PlayAgain (Get calls when the game finishs):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_gamefinished);

    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow()
            .getAttributes();
    params.width = android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes(
            (android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

            setListeners();
}

public void setListeners() {

    button_restart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppData.restartGame = true;
            finish();
        }
    });

    button_mainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppData.finishMe = true;
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

The only other things that are relavent are that I use an AsyncTask and a Handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ObAt, I have exactly same error in my application. You wrote you don't use IntentReceiver, but it's probably not true.

Seems you're using special feature of Samsung devices - MultiWindow, so if you have registered intent-filter in your manifest, like me:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <!-- SAMSUNG MULTI-WINDOW -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- SAMSUNG MULTI-WINDOW -->   
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.minimode.icon.portrait.normal"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.minimode.icon.landscape.normal"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

then probably Samsung device register IntentReceiver on it's own on background to correctly handle some tasks related to MultiWindow feature. I see this error in log for a few months and it never had any issues. So I just ignore this till Samsung fix this problem on their side. This is just how I see it

Comment: I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 with JB (so it has MultiWindow), that will explain a lot! I will test it but thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error,  you are are leaking a IntentReceiver you registered previously.

you need to unregister the IntentReceiver,   the `onPause` method would be a good place to do this for your `SimpleMath` activity.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregister(); //  here
}
```

Comment: I don't use onPause in SimpleMath, I only Override onResume. 'The method unregister() is undefined '

Comment: you should! the `onPause` is the perfect place to unregister the receiver you made so that you dont leak it when going to the next activity.

Comment: Thank you! But hwo do I call unregister? Eclipse cannot find this method.

Comment: I cannot help you any further without seeing your `SimpleMath` activity code. CAn you edit your question and add it there ?

Comment: The weird thing is that I'd never used an IntentReceiver