# Leaked IntentReceiver only in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-leaks, broadcastreceiver

*Before posting any solution I request you to read completely*

**Problem:**

Facing below exception

```
03-12 14:13:20.936: E/ActivityThread(6629): Activity
com.sec.android.app.videoplayer.activity.VPVideoPlayer has leaked IntentReceiver
com.android.internal.policy.impl.multiwindow.MultiPhoneWindowEvent$3@424e3698 that
was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

when user switches screen orientation from landscape to portrait after a video is opened  via one of the activity and after the video finishes `the app closes Unfortunately`.

> **Observed only in Samsung n 8000 device till now**

**After search:**

Every where I was getting solution related to `registerReceiver` & `unregisterReceiver`.But the code here in the activity does not have anything like this.So don't know what should I do to resolve it.

**Scenario:**

Suppost I have `activity1` which calls `activity2`.

All the activities `screenOrientation="landscape"`

Now assume `activity2` is as follows:

```
public class activity2 extends Activity {

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //initialize UI
            ....
       /*call asynctask to download file(file can be of any format i.e.pdf,
        video,etc)*/
      try {
                new DownloadAndOpenFile().execute(filePath);
          } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
```

After file is downloaded,it's opened using the below method:-

```
public void openDownloadedFile(String filePath) {
        try {

            Uri data = Uri.parse(filePath);

            String type = getMimeType(data.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AlertDialog alertDialog = AlertDialogBox.alertDialog(this,
                    "No Supported Application found to open this file");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

When video finished, the control should go to `Activity1` so `Activity2`'s `onRestart()` is as below:

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {

        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(tag, "In onRestart");
        finish();
    }
```

There must be going something wrong,it's obvious.But don't know how to correct it.

Please help in finding a relevant solution to the above problem.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Where you are registering receiver??

Comment: Please let me know in case any further info is needed\

Comment: @Kalyan :There is no receiver involved..the code works fine in landscape mode

Comment: post code of VPVideoPlayer

Comment: VPVideo player is default player in Samsung device...It's even crashing when tested in mxplayer

Comment: Don't have their code

Comment: may be you need to add this line to your Activity manifest **<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />**

Comment: checkout this same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362883/activity-does-not-start

Comment: but why is it unfortunately closing only in Portrait mode.also why is it not happening in Samsung Tab2 gt- p3100...